# Nextcloud Nginx Reverse Proxy MIME Type problems

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I am running Nextcloud in a container setup in FPM mode. The app container itself runs the `php-fpm` component, I have an additional container running nginx as web server. I am following this example very closely:

https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy-self-signed-ssl/mariadb/fpm

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:17.0.1-fpm-alpine
    container_name: nextcloud
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./config/mariadb_nextcloud.env
    
  nextcloud-web:
    build: ./nextcloud-web
    container_name: nextcloud-web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST={{ nextcloud_external_url }}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST={{ nextcloud_external_url }}
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud
```

This is the `nginx.conf` file that gets copied into the nextcloud-web container (based on Nginx, no further changes except for adding the config file):

```
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream php-handler {
        server nextcloud:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Add headers to serve security related headers
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
        # topic first.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;
        #
        # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
        # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
        # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
        # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
        # could take several months.
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

        # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        # Path to the root of your installation
        root /var/www/html;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
        # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

        # The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
        # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;

        location = /.well-known/carddav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }

        location = /.well-known/caldav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            # fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

            # Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;

            # Enable pretty urls
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js, css and map files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
            # have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
            # this topic first.
            #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;" always;
            #
            # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
            # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
            # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
            # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
            # could take several months.
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header X-Download-Options "noopen" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none" always;
            add_header X-Robots-Tag "none" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap|mp4|webm)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the standard configuration from the link above. In front of this container I'm using the well-known `Nginx-proxy` container with letsencrypt companion. Most of the Nextcloud installation works (web frontend, upload / download, the apps, most of the admin portal). I however recently installed a custom app (SAML configuration) and the management page of this does not load, but instead gives me loads of the following errors:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").
The resource from “https://<my-url>.tld/apps/files/” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “https://<my-url>.tld/apps/files/” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “https://<my-url>.tld/apps/files/” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Any idea what's going on here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a file permission problem. The web container did not have read access to the `custom_apps` folder and thus could not serve the requested file. Why it doesn't give a more meaningful error message I cannot tell.

Comment: Nginx probably returned an http error page for those requests, that's why CSP tripped before you could see any other errors from the frontend.